# Create react native library error with swift files

Tags: reactjs, swift, xcode, native

I have a problem with react native especially with create-react-native-library
the project created successfully but when add new swift file, I keep find "file name" can not be find in scope

I created the swift file in Xcode and it auto complete the file name, so I expected to run smoothly but react native keep showing file "test" not found in scope